# Framework to Map/Replace/Process a string

Tags: java, string, parsing, frameworks, mapping

I am processing many **CSV** files and looking, therefore, for a small Java Framework which maps many Strings into one String.

Example 1:

> "abc", "abc xy" "abc xyz", "xyz" should be replaced with "abc"

Example 2:

> "defg", "defg xy" should be replaced with "defg"

and so on.

Does anyone know such a kind of framework?
Thank you!

Additional info:

I would like to do something like this:

```
for reading many csv-cells
   handling lots of different cases;
   ...
   String s = current csv-cell content;
   s = Framework.replaceIfNecessary(s);
   ...
   save data etc.;
next
```

Of course, I could build such a functionality using a Dictionary class myself. But as it seams to me to be a standard case when parsing huge files I figured that there might be a elegant solution.

Comment: What is the logic behind returning "abc" for those four strings in your first example?  Is it because the majority of them have "abc" as the first whitespace-delimited word, or do you simply want to return the first String in a list of Strings?

Comment: Actually, there is no logic, it is just a bad chosen example. It could be replaced by any other String, lets say "mno". In general, if a String is part of a defined set of Strings it should be replaced with a specific String.

Comment: Can you include some sample code in your question that illustrates how you would use such a framework if it existed?

Comment: I added some illustration of my wish. Thank you for your help!

Comment: How would the framework know what "replace if necessary" means?

Comment: Preferable some kind of config-file in which it is specified which Strings should be replaced.

Comment: That information is critical to your question and should be included there.  If you could show an example of what such a config file might look like, that would also be helpful.